# Autotune PID a controller

Tags: control, pid-controller

I would like to automatically tune a PID controller. Is there a method that I can use to get the frequency and timing characteristics I want and automatically tune the PID loop?

Concerning industrial controllers,do they use old process data or automate online pid tunning algorithms such as ziegler nichols?

Comment: Google System Identification or Parameter Optimization

Comment: I am a big proponent of the Astrom-Hagglund Relay Tuning method: http://www.controleng.com/search/search-single-display/relay-method-automates-pid-loop-tuning/4a5774decc.html. I tried it a couple of years ago on a temperature control project and it worked very well (you can see I asked a question about it in my post history).

Comment: The most simple way is to use a interactive scheme, with Ti canceling the biggest time constant, and Kp canceling the process gain. If your process under a second order, you can avoid the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to automatically tune a PID controller.

Please be more specific here. Do you (1) expect the characteristics of the plant to change over time, or (2) just not have a good model of the plant?

If (1): the broadest possible way to attack this sort of problem is using adaptive control techniques, but these are also often very difficult to apply practically and require a lot of mathematical background. If you have some sort of system knowledge and some model of the system and how it changes, I recommend gain scheduling, which basically comes up with a new set of PID gains for different regions of the parameter space, and uses some system ID technique (e.g. a Kalman Filter) available from the observable states to estimate which PID to use based on how the system is performing.

If (2): If you don't have a model then you basically have to use an empirical tuning technique. Ziegler-Nichols is almost never used because it's too aggressive, but the comments have some good suggestions. The book by [Astrom and Hagglund](https://aiecp.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/1-0-1-k-j-astrom-pid-controllers-theory-design-and-tuning-2ed.pdf) on PID controllers has tons of these techniques, and is an essential reference for anyone serious about process control. If you *do* have a model (even a low-fidelity one), you can use everything you know about classical controller design in the frequency domain (transfer functions, root-locus, bode/nyquist plots) to get the relevant controller quality parameters.

Comment: I am open to suggestions.To be more specific ,I have a process data.I Need to build an algorithm to calculate parameters for the pid controller in an automated way.

Comment: @chiplusplus I don't see how you manage to achieve that, such method require a lot of knowledge about modal identification. Will the process change over time?

Comment: @MathieuL To simplify let's assume that it won't change.

Comment: @chiplusplus if the process don't change, the simple way is to find the order of the system, you want to have the lowest order possible, after that, you can use very simple setting like if it is a first order, you set Ti = T1 and you set Kc = 1/Kp where T1 is the process time constant and Kp is the process's gain. With these setting, your command will respond at the same dynamic of the process and you will reach zero error in Permanent regime. If you want more help, you should precise what is the process.